# How to get count of non-NA raster cells within polygon

Tags: r, extract, polygon, raster

I've been running into all sorts of issues using ArcGIS ZonalStats and thought R could be a great way. Saying that I'm fairly new to R, but got a coding background.
The situation is that I have several rasters and a polygon shape file with many features of different sizes (though all features are bigger than a raster cell and the polygon features are aligned to the raster).
I've figured out how to get the mean value for each polygon feature using the raster library with extract:

```
#load packages required
require(rgdal)
require(sp)
require(raster)
require(maptools)
# ---Set the working directory-------
datdir <- "/test_data/"

#Read in a ESRI grid of water depth
ras <- readGDAL("test_data/raster/pl_sm_rp1000/w001001.adf")
#convert it to a format recognizable by the raster package
ras <- raster(ras)

#read in polygon shape file
proxNA <- readShapePoly("test_data/proxy/PL_proxy_WD_NA_test") 
#plot raster and shp
plot(ras)
plot(proxNA)

#calc mean depth per polygon feature
#unweighted - only assigns grid to district if centroid is in that district
proxNA@data$RP1000 <- extract(ras, proxNA, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE, weights = FALSE)
#check results
head(proxNA)

#plot depth values 
spplot(proxNA[,'RP1000'])
```

The issue I have is that I also need an area based ratio between the area of the polygon and all non NA cells in the same polygon. I know what the cell size of the raster is and I can get the area for each polygon, but the missing link is the count of all non-NA cells in each feature. I managed to get the cell number of all the cells in the polygon `proxNA@data$Cnumb1000 <- cellFromPolygon(ras, proxNA)`and I'm sure there is a way to get the actual value of the raster cell, which then requires a loop to get the number of all non-NA cells combined with a count, etc.
BUT, I'm sure there is a much better and quicker way to do that! If any of you has an idea or can point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Sorry, I think I misplaced this question and have therefore moved it to the gis-stackoverflow site. [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84387/how-to-get-count-of-non-na-raster-cells-within-polygon-using-r) Many Thanks to those you had a look so far!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to your files, but based on what you described, this should work:

```
library(raster)
mask_layer=shapefile(paste0(shapedir,"AOI.shp"))
original_raster=raster(paste0(template_raster_dir,"temp_raster_DecDeg250.tif"))
nonNA_raster=!is.na(original_raster)
masked_img=mask(nonNA_raster,mask_layer) #based on centroid location of cells
nonNA_count=cellStats(masked_img, sum)
```